# ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied when connecting to OracleDB through SSMA

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

> ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

We are currently migrating the contents of Oracle DB to SQL Server.

I'm using SSMA 9.3v and I have Oracle 11g to connect to.

You have installed the Oracle 11.2 client for the connection and are in the process of accessing ODP.net .

> ORA-01017: invalid username/password; login denied status after login information is accessed.

CMD confirmed that the connection through SQLPLUS is successful.

Both Standard mode and TNS mode have the same problem

Do you happen to know a solution to this error?

Comment: SSMA = Sql Server Migration Assistant ?

Answer (score 1):

"ORA-01017: invalid username/password" is a "good result", in the sense that it means you successfully contacted a database, and it understood your request.

So what this means is, one of the following:

a) you have contacted the wrong database. This might be "indirectly" wrong. For example, if you are using a entry from a tnsnames.ora file then you might be pointing at the wrong file.

b) your username is wrong.

c) your password is wrong (passwords are typically case-sensitive depending on your settings).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.

Tested for a,b,c Therefore, I think there is no problem.

Could you please let me know if this problem can occur because I don't have the authority?